# How do I prevent page reload when a user is scrolling down on the touch screen

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, page-refresh

When a user is scrolling down from the top of the page to get more content, the page reloads instead. This happens when there is no other content to scroll down.
**This is a problem of Chrome and opera mobile browsers**. 
The example shown on [this site](http://babich.biz/pull-to-refresh-ui-pattern/) is exactly what happens and that is what i'm trying to prevent.
This is my code:

```
    <style id="compiled-css" type="text/css">

          body {
            overscroll-behavior: contain;
            width: 100%;
          }

          #scroller {
            overflow-y:auto;
            padding:0;
            margin:0
            border:1px solid #eee;
            width:100%;
            height:500px;
            bottom:23px;
            }
            .btn{
                height:4.2em;
                border-radius:10px;
                color: #E5787A;
                float:right;
                background: #78E5E3;
            }
            blockquote {
                background: #B9DFF1;
                padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                text-align: justify;
                color:#333;
                border-radius:15px;
                font-size: 1.0em;
                font-family:'Josefin Slab Thin';
                line-height: 1.6em;
                align-text:center;
                max-height: 350px;
                box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #78E5E3;
                -ms-word-break: break-all;
                word-break: break-all;
                word-break: break-word;
                -ms-hyphens: auto;
                -moz-hyphens: auto;
                hyphens: auto;
                -webkit-hyphens: auto;
                overflow-wrap: break-word;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                overflow: hidden;
                }

            .container-margin {
              margin-left: -15px;
              margin-right: -15px;
              }
            html {
                overflow: scroll;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar {
                width: 0px;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
                background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
            }
            /* Optional: show position indicator in red */
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
                background: white;
            }

      </style>
</head>

<body id="content">
    <div id="scroller" class="scroller col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="height:450px;width:100%;background-color: white;">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="message right appeared">
                <blockquote>
                  {{=message}}
                </blockquote>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="message left appeared">
                <blockquote>
                {{=answer}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have done this, but doesn't seem to help:

```
<script>
$("#home").click(function()
{
   $("#content").load("home.html");
   return false;
});
</script>

body {
  /* Disables pull-to-refresh but allows overscroll glow effects. */
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what the problem is. You said *My code works [pretty] well but when a user is scrolling down from the top of the page to get more content, the page reloads instead.* But isn't that the effect of pull-to-refresh? Or do you want to disable pull-to-refresh completely? Also, scrolling down is an opposite action where the touch starts from bottom moving to the top of the screen.

Comment: I want to prevent the page reload on pull down.

Comment: I meant the code is OK for the purpose of it works not scroll. What I need is preventing the reload.

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior), to remove the refresh behaviour, you can use `overscroll-behavior: none` on the `body`

Comment: still not working on both chrome and opera, I also tried overscroll-behavior-y: contain; and  overscroll-behavior-y: none; and they both do not work.

Comment: just tried overscroll-behavior: none on body, works perfectly in chrome android